# How to get both absolute and relative line numbers in ideavim for IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, vim-plugin, intellij-plugin, ideavim

I am using IntelliJ IDE for my projects and just installed ideamvim plugin. In the `.ideavimrc` I added this property

`set rnu`

with this property I get relative line numbers in my files in intellij which is amazing. But can I **ALSO** get absolute line numbers? In my vscode, I have both absolute line numbers and relative line numbers, so I was wondering if it was possible to get the same behavior in intellij?

I am fine even if I have to install a new plugin in Intellij for this feature to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 26):

You can do both `set relativenumber` and `set number`. This will give you absolute line number for the current line, but relative line numbers for everything else. You can't have two sets of numbers side by side.

Comment: I have it setup in vscode. Check this image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM70W.png . I am new to vim, so I am not sure if its because of vscode's implementation.

Comment: Yeah, this is a VSCode peculiarity. Standard Vim doesn't support this (maybe through a plugin?) and IdeaVim doesn't support it, either.

Comment: The respective command is `set number relativenumber`, so you can copy-paste :)

Comment: `set number relativenumber` for some reason, this doesn't work in ideamvim for me.

Answer (score 13):

You can download and install manual this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7414-relative-line-numbers/versions

And:

1. Download the latest jar from here
2. Open Application folder, find the IntelliJ or Android Studio (or other JetBrains IDEs)
3. Put the *relative-line-numbers.jar* file into **plugins** folder
4. Restart your IntelliJ or Android Studio (or other JetBrains IDEs)

It worked at IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2 and windows 11
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4mBp.png]

Comment: Works on macOS 11.2.3 using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3

Comment: It says "Not compatible with the version of your running IDE (CLion 2022.1.3)", but it works well. Maybe we just need to repackage it?

Answer (score 12):

### You *can* have "hybrid" numbering

Add this line to your `~/.ideavimrc` file as per the [documentation](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/doc/set-commands.md).

`set number relativenumber`

### You *can't* have context-sensitive numbering

Automatic toggling between relative / absolute numbering as you can in Vim with

```
autocmd InsertEnter * : set norelativenumber
autocmd InsertLeave * : set relativenumber
```

... this doesn't work because IdeaVIM doesn't support `autocmd`.

Comment: I guess that's the limitation of vim and intellij. Check the vscode image I posted in the above comment. In vscode I am able to get both.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get this to work in Intellij 2019 version. As of today this method doesn't work in latest Intellij version.

1. Install [Relative Line Numbers](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7414-relative-line-numbers) plugin in intellij, we will use this plugin to simulate **relative line numbers**.
2. On the other hand, we will let ideavim simulate **absolute line numbers**. This can be done by adding `set nu` to your `.ideavimrc` file. You can directly open this file by clicking IdeaVim icon in bottom right of intellij. If not just search for this file. For me its in `C:\Users\{userName}\.ideavimrc`

After doing the above, you should have something that looks like this:

[image]

Note: The comments on the plugin website mention that it doesn't work for latest(2020 version) IntelliJ. I am using 2019 version and it works fine so far. The only problem I have noticed so far on my end is that when you open VCS window, you only get relative line numbers(for some reason ideavim buffer doesn't kick in). I will update this answer if I find any other issues. Until then I will keep this question open in case someone else has a working solution for latest intellij version.

Answer (score 1):

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7414-relative-line-numbers

> For anyone who wants to use this plugins in new version of intelliJ or
> AndroidStudio (or other JetBrains IDEs): [on macOS]       Download the
> latest jar from here      Open Application folder, find the IntelliJ or
> Android Studio (or other JetBrains IDEs)      Right click -> Show Package
> Contents      Put the relative-line-numbers.jar file
> into Contents/plugins folder      Restart your IntelliJ or Android Studio
> (or other JetBrains IDEs)         Find the Relative Line Numbers plugins in
> the bundled plugin area       Just enable it! Tested by myself, it WORKS
> on Android Studio 4.2 Beta

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The latest version (0.64) ideavim works. Set number and set relative number.

[image].

Comment: Actually this is not what the question that I asked. This was possible even before the latest ideavim version. What I want is to have both absolute and relative numbers on "ALL LINES", not just the line my cursor is on. Check this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM70W.png. I have set it up on my vscode but only in intellij I am not able to replicate this feature.